# How to safely store OAuth response file of each user provided by google drive api

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am working on an asp.net application where I ask people to give the authorization (using `OAuth`) for accessing their google drive (to a particular folder) to be able to list the files within the application.

The following code enables users to provide authorization and creates a corresponding `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses` file in the server to be used for future requests. But, this request will happen for each user, which will create more OAuth response files. I am not sure how to design the application and store these files safely. Probably, I may create a new folder (using the `Guid-based UserIds`) for each user and save the file in that folder. Does this make sense? Or do you recommend another approach?

```
using (var stream =
    new FileStream("Services/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}

BaseClientService.Initializer bcs = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
bcs.HttpClientInitializer = credential;

DriveService service = new DriveService(bcs);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Correction

> I am working on an asp.net application where I ask people to give the authorization (using OAuth) for accessing their google drive (to a particular folder) to be able to list the files within the application.

When you request access Its going to be for the users full drive account its not going to be just for one folder.

## Storing credential files.

Your question is a bit hard to understand but I think you are asking where you should store your credential files.  The way `FileDataStore` works is that it creates a new file for each `"user"` so depending upon what you have set for "user" a file will be created as you can see i tend to use a guid at the end and store that in a session var that way i know when the user comes back with this session var its that file i need to grab for them.  Actually the client library does all that for you because as soon as it sees the id it will use that automatically.

[image]

## Web vs installed application.

I do have one major comment if you are using Asp .net and intend to use a web application then you are using the wrong code. The following sample shows how to authenticate using [Web appliations asp.net mvc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) note the session in the code below.

```
 public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
```